# Smartlocation possible memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm not sure, but I think I stumbled upon a memory leak in the third-party library SmartLocation (https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib). Here is the code I'm using to reproduce the leak:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MyApplication.refWatcher.watch(this)

    SmartLocation.with(this)
            .location()
            .config(LocationParams.NAVIGATION)
            .oneFix()
            .start {
                Timber.d("location: $it")
            }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    SmartLocation.with(this)
            .location()
            .stop()
}
```

}

I'm using the latest version of the library:

```
compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'
```

After changing my phone's orientation 5 times I can see 5 instances of my activity in the memory profiler:

memory profiler

[image]

And here is what I see in the YourKit:

[image]

Leakcanary also getting triggered after orientation chages, bot for some reason it doesn't show anything.

leakcanary

[image]

And here is also StrictMode log:

```
E/StrictMode: class com.example.kirakishou.smartlocationmemleaktest.MainActivity; instances=4; limit=1
          android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.example.kirakishou.smartlocationmemleaktest.MainActivity; instances=4; limit=1
              at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
```

Comment: pass the application context.

Comment: Yeah, that solved the problem. Thanks.